# Hibernate: Missing artifact commons-logging

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dependencies

I was about to get started with Hibernate, so fom maven.org I took the pom of org.hibernate:hibernate:3.6.0.Beta2. [(link)](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/hibernate/3.6.0.Beta2/hibernate-3.6.0.Beta2.pom). I just copy-pasted as-is.

However I got the error: 
*Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:99.0-does-not-exist*

It seems that in the parent pom, there is this commons-logging dependency, and it says that it's missing. Should I have used some other pom?

Comment: Just a question why are you copy pasting pom and can't add dependency directly from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate in your pom.xml?

Comment: @DhruvPal because the missing dependency is not in my own pom, but in the referenced parent pom. The parent pom is referenced from my pom file, however I cannot modify the parent pom where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added the wrong dependency. I should've added:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```